# Is there an equivalent of AffineTransform.createTransformedShape(Shape) in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, awt

In JavaFX 2.2, it seems like you can't do much with `Transform` objects except add them to `Node`s. In particular, there's no algebraic operations so that you can compose one transformation with another.

I suppose the reason is that most of the calculations should be done by the GPU directly, so not letting people try to do it programmatically prevents some slowdown.

But sometimes you really do want to know what the final result of applying a transformation is. In particular, `java.awt.geom.AffineTransform` has this nice method `createTransformedShape` that would turn a `java.awt.Shape` into the equivalent shape under the given transformation. I can't find anything equivalent in JavaFX, and I can't think of a workaround.

Am I missing something or does anyone have a clever idea that doesn't involve re-implementing the `Shape` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that an exact equivalent of `AffineTransform.createTransformedShape` was added to Java 8.  You can however apply a transform to a shape by adding a transform to the [shape's transform list](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getTransforms%28%29).  So in a way, a transformed shape is just a shape with some custom transforms in it's transform list.

The Transform functions in JavaFX were greatly enhance for [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net) allowing [composition of transformations](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/transform/Transform.html#createConcatenation-javafx.scene.transform.Transform-).  In addition various vector like algebraic operations were added the [Point2D](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/geometry/Point2D.html) and [Point3D](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/geometry/Point3D.html) classes.

Comment: In the AWT, things like `Arc2D`, `Ellipse2D`, `Rectangle2D`, etc. all implemented `Shape`, which guaranteed that they were composed of `Path` segments. And you could peek inside and see what kinds of paths they were and which coordinates they started at. It appears that JavaFX doesn't allow that, so that if you wanted to, for example, compute the `Path` that's equivalent to a geometric shape, you'd have to do it yourself. I mean, not even `Polygon` and `Polyline` extend `Path` in JavaFX. I have to guess that's for OpenGL goodness, but it's a little annoying.